# Use field names in combobox

Tags: vb.net, vb, arcgis-explorer

I am currently stuck on a problem surrounding ArcGIS Explorer and comboboxes

What I am trying to do is use 3 comboboxes to do the following:

1. View all features contained within ArcExplorer's table of Contents
2. View the selected layers containing field names
3. View unique attributes for the fields

All of these would go in 3 seperate comboboxes.

Would anyone have any suggestions on working through this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not done any development with ArcGIS Explorer so this is just a suggestion, but take a look at the [SDK help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisexplorer/1500/sdk/index.html) and just start tinkering. It looks like a pretty light weight API compared to ArcObjects so it shouldn't be too hard to put something together.

Start with the [Mapping](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisexplorer/1500/sdk/componenthelp/index.html#/ESRI_ArcGISExplorer_Mapping_Class_Diagram/00030000054m000000/) and [Data](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisexplorer/1500/sdk/componenthelp/index.html#/ESRI_ArcGISExplorer_Data_Class_Diagram/000300000n6s000000/) namespaces and look at some of the "how-to's" such as [How to create add-in projects](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisexplorer/1500/sdk/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_create_add_in_projects/000200000038000000/) and [How to access data in a table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisexplorer/1500/sdk/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_access_data_in_a_Table/00020000000s000000/).

For getting the unique values of a collection, you could use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)'s [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) operator or copy it into a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Since this is all basic .NET functionality I'd suggest doing some further research on your own on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0x726c2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) and come back if you still have trouble.

It doesn't look like there is much activity on the [arcgis-explorer](/questions/tagged/arcgis-explorer) tag though so you might have to be patient.

Comment: Hi I have worked through a chunk of this but I have now become stuck at an sql query issue. I have posted a new question regarding this at this following link:

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22091/sql-arcexplorer-sdk-question

If anyone has input regarding SQL or could see if they spot the issue in my code I would be much appreciative!