# Creating SQL query in ArcGIS Explorer SDK?

Tags: sql, vb.net, arcgis-explorer

I am using the [ArcGIS Explorer SDK](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisexplorer/1500/sdk/conceptualhelp/index.html) and have run into an issue surrounding a query I would like to perform with SQL. I believe my query is built wrong or perhaps I am looking at the wrong fields. Would anyone have any input on my code below and/or possible solutions?

I would like the code to query a column for specific values then return them into a combo box. My query simply returns a blank value at the moment. Below is the code for that block.

```vb
Try
    Dim md As MapDisplay = ESRI.ArcGISExplorer.Application.Application.ActiveMapDisplay
        Dim map As Map = md.Map
        Dim cblayernameselect As MapItem = cblayername.SelectedItem
        Dim cbfieldnameselect As String = cbfieldname.SelectedItem
        Dim selitem As SelectedItemsCollection = ESRI.ArcGISExplorer.Application.Application.SelectedItems

        cbattribute.Items.Clear()

        selitem.Select(cblayernameselect)

        Dim child As PackageChildLayer = TryCast(ESRI.ArcGISExplorer.Application.Application.SelectedItems(0), PackageChildLayer)
        Dim layertable As Table = child.Table

        Dim cbcolumn As Column = layertable.Columns.Item(cbfieldnameselect)

        Dim whereclause As String = "SELECT " & cbcolumn.Name & " FROM " & layertable.Name

        Dim rows As RowCollection = layertable.Search(New Filter(whereclause))


        For Each row In rows
            cbattribute.Items.Add(row)
        Next row

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without reading all of your question I will guess the answer! You are sending a complete T-SQL 'SELECT' statement when the QueryFilter WhereClause property is just that - a where clause (what comes after the 'WHERE' keyword.) Create a QueryFilter with a valid WhereClause and populate the SubFields property with the fields you want returned.

Comment: Would you have any idea how this would work for a Distinct selection?

For example I would like to SELECT DISTINCT columnname FROM table

I unfortunatly haven't been able to fit this into the whereclause. My returned query is always blank unfortunatly.

Comment: .SubFields can be prefaced with a "DISTINCT" clause. 

.WhereClause is what comes after "WHERE." 

.SubFields is what goes between "SELECT" and "WHERE."

Comment: BTW - you can cast to IQueryFilterDefinition to add an "ORDER BY" clause to the .PostFixClause property.